# changing the color of an unfocused selected datagrid row

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have implemented a context menu on my data grid rows.  When you right click a row, it briefly highlights it before opening the context menu. By my understanding, this is because the datagrid is losing focus.

I am attempting to change the unfocused-yet-selected color using `SystemColors.ControlBrushKey`, but it has no effect. Is this incorrect? I have found a few `ListBox` related solutions where this is the accepted solution.

```
<Style x:Key="DefaultRowStyle" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
    <Style.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" Color="Black" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Yellow" />
    </Style.Resources>
</Style>
```

Full list of system colors for reference: http://blogs.msdn.com/cfs-filesystemfile.ashx/__key/CommunityServer-Blogs-Components-WeblogFiles/00-00-01-38-64-SystemColors+Reference/6266.swatch_5F00_Amalgam.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your only option is to copy the Style XAML from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff506248%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and change the color setting in it.  The comments in the XAML suggest that a bunch of the states in the XAML they've provided are indistinguishable unless you change the style.

```
<VisualState x:Name="Unfocused_Selected">
  <Storyboard>
    <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="DGR_Border" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[0].(GradientStop.Color)">
      <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ControlMediumColor}" />
    </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="DGR_Border" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)">
      <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ControlDarkColor}" />
    </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
  </Storyboard>
</VisualState>
```

Edit: I linked the wrong page.  That is the style for Silverlight (doh!).  I've fixed the link to point to the WPF style.  I've also copied the applicable area of the WPF style.

Comment: I copied out the `Setter` for the Template.  When I paste it into my project, it says that `DataGridRow` doesn't exist as part of the `System.Windows.Controls` namespace, same goes with all the elements attempting to be accessed on the `localprimitives` namespace

Comment: I was looking at the silverlight styles.  I've updated for WPF.

Comment: Ha. So this works, but only partially. Only the end of the row after all columns have ended is highlighted. In fact it highlights the exact opposite piece of the row that is highlighted by default